# Issue with Reordable CollectiveView - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the `LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout` to work with my needs here for being able to rearrange my `CollectionView`.  I've been implementing the basics to get that demo working with my code and I keep hitting a road block with:

```
PlayingCard *playingCard = self.deck[indexPath.item];
    PlayingCardCell *playingCardCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlayingCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    playingCardCell.playingCard = playingCard;
    return playingCardCell;
```

`PlayingCardCell.playingCard = playingCard` keeps giving me `[UICollectionViewCell setPlayingCard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155620c30'`  Now I understand that this is not seeing the instance but I've implemented all of my header files associated and tried to even make that `instance` public.

```
- (void)setPlayingCard:(PlayingCard *)playingCard {
    _playingCard = playingCard;
    self.playingCardImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_playingCard.imageName];
}
```

My setup is based off a `UITabBarController` that switches `ViewControllers`, within this specific `view` I have a custom `ViewController` class that created a custom `UICollectionController`.

Maybe its because it is a `ViewController` rather than a `CollectionView`?

Suggestions, thoughts?

https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlayingCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]` is actually returning a `UICollectionViewCell` instead of your custom class.

Do you create your cell appearance in a storyboard? If so, can you check that in the storyboard, your cell has the custom class set to `PlayingCardCell` (your custom collection view cell class) and not to `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: I am creating everything throough straight objective c other than the ViewController